# Patterns for UI test Automation

Tags: .net, design-patterns, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm currently automation a plugging for MS Office. We are creating Coded UI tests in VS 2010. As an option I could use the "Coded UI test builder" tool, but it does not suite in my case. So I created my own UI Map class and extension methods for each UI Control/Map where i add different action functionality, for example press buttons or asserting some UI values. The scenarios of the test cases are in the test classes.

I am new in this area and also I'm new in working as a automation tester.
May be you could share your experience or advice some good practices and practice for test automation (from a programming/design point of view)

Comment: Could you clarify the question?  Is there a specific problem, or are you just looking for general advice?  If you are looking for general advice, you may want to try http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: There is no question here, just a suggestive "Maybe you could share your experience...". Hmm...as there is no way to give the right answer, I won't try one.

Comment: totally agree with you. I'm new in automation testing, so I asked this question. but i fount you that there a deferent automation test methodologies for example: "Keyword-driven testing", "Data-driven testing" etc. which really help me. But i understood that the programming design patterns are also applied for coding test automation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is List of 10 best practices for UI Test Automation:

http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2011/01/ui-test-automation-best-practices.html

Comment: It would be more helpful to list them here.

Answer (score 6):

The good practices that apply to test automation and design are the same as for good programming in general.

When you're coding for test automation, you should apply the same criteria for whether or not you apply a design pattern as for when you are coding in any other situation. There is no difference.